# Can't write to stdin with popen opened with write

Tags: c, stdin, popen

I'm trying to create a GUI for the linux version of windscribe, so I wish to communicate with the windscribe CLI from my C program. I chose to use popen.

I can write single commands with popen("command", "w"), but I want to add informations when asked, like login in the CLI :

```
$ windscribe login
Windscribe Username: myname
Windscribe Password: mypassword
```

So I keep the FILE opened and use fputs to keep sending informations.
I finally wrote this function:

```
void write_in_shell_commands(char** commands, int length){
    FILE *fp = NULL;

    // sending first command
    if (length > 0) {
        debug("Writing \"%s\" to shell.", commands[0]);
        fp = popen(commands[0], "w");
    }

    // sending the rest
    if (fp) {
        debug("File successfully opened.");

        for (int i = 1; i < length; i++){
            debug("%s", "Writing to shell.");
            fputs(commands[i], fp);
        }

        pclose(fp);
    } else {
        debug("Operation failed.");
    }
}
```

But when I use this function (e.g.) for login, it doesn't behave as I expected, it seems the additional commands are lost and not taken into account.

```
char* cmd1 = "windscribe login";
char* cmd2 = "myname";
char* cmd3 = "mypassword";

char** commands = malloc(3 * sizeof(char*));
commands[0] = cmd1;
commands[1] = cmd2;
commands[2] = cmd3;

write_in_shell_commands(commands, 3);
```

I expect the program to :

1. Write cmd1 in shell
2. Write cmd2 in stdin
3. Write cmd3 in stdin

But actually this happens

```
DEBUG output/shellwriter.c:22: Writing "windscribe login" to shell. 
DEBUG output/shellwriter.c:27: File successfully opened. 
DEBUG output/shellwriter.c:30: Writing to shell. 
DEBUG output/shellwriter.c:30: Writing to shell. 
Windscribe Password: Windscribe Username:
```

It's actually asking for the password in the terminal and eventually fails because credentials are bad.

What's actually happening here ? Where are my second and third commands ? Am I using the wrong functions ?

Comment: The argument to the [`malloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) function is the number of ***bytes*** you want to allocate. There are few, if any, systems where pointers are a single byte.

Comment: malloc(3) means allocating 3 bytes. Probably should be malloc(3*sizeof(char*))

Comment: As for the output written to the terminal, it could be messed up depending on how the program writes to the terminal as well as due to buffering issues.

Comment: my bad for the malloc, noob error from my part. I edited it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude So is it something I can access/interact with ? I didn't see another way of writing multiple commands than fputc/fputs to file pointer

Comment: If the program you execute does things with the terminal (like writing special control codes to disable echoing and similar) then there's really nothing you can do. Perhaps try to add a small delay between each `fputs` call to see if it helps?

Comment: If the program is secure, it will attempt to put the terminal into noecho mode before reading a password. And it probably won't even read input from `stdin`, it will probably interact with `/dev/tty` directly. (This is how `ssh` password auth works, for example.) If you want to feed it a password, `popen` is going to be insufficient. You'll need to allocate a pty for the program to run in and feed input into that instead. Probably you'll want to use a tool like `expect` rather than writing that yourself.

Comment: Ok so I made a small program that asks for a input and exits. And I can communicate with it with popen and fputs. Si I guess the problem is what @DanielPryden explained. I'll check this out then

Answer (score 0):

`cmd1, cmd2, cmd3` are pointers to char. So you should allocate memory for 3 pointers to `char` for `commands` which is a pointer to pointer to char.

```
char** commands = malloc(3*sizeof(char*));
```